# update column adding a suffix to duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

column `title` is like this:

```
gold
blue night
silver morning
about earth 
sun vs king
blue night
```

So there are duplicates (in the above case - `blue night`).

I need to rename all duplicates adding `-02`, `-03` ... at the end.

For example second `blue night` should be `blue-night-02`

If there is third `blue night` it should be `blue-night-03` and so on.

Any help?

Comment: do you've any code snippet? do you need it on php ?

Comment: @don'tangryme, yes I need it in php

Comment: then post your array with title

Comment: I've added an shorter version of answer. Hope it helps :) Have a look

Comment: excellent, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More concise way using `array_count_values()`,

```
<?php
$title = ['gold','blue night','silver morning','about earth','sun vs king','blue night','about earth','gold','about earth'];

$value_counts = array_count_values($title);
#print_r($value_counts);
$expected_result = [];
foreach($value_counts as $k=>$v){
    if($v<2){
        $expected_result[] = $k;
    }else{
        $expected_result[] = $k;
        for($i=2;$i<=$v;$i++){
            $expected_result[] = $k."-".$i; 
        }
    }
}

print_r($expected_result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( 
  [0] => gold
  [1] => gold-2
  [2] => blue night
  [3] => blue night-2
  [4] => silver morning 
  [5] => about earth
  [6] => about earth-2 
  [7] => about earth-3 
  [8] => sun vs king
 )
```

**DEMO:**https://3v4l.org/Hj1Yg

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple using an array entry as counter (maybe not the most elaborate way to do it, but possible):

```
<?PHP
$str = "gold
blue night
silver morning
about earth 
sun vs king
blue night";

$words = explode("\n",$str);
$matches = array();
$wordsConverted = array();

foreach($words as $word)
{
    if(isset($matches[$word]))
    {
        if($matches[$word] > 10)
        {
            $wordsConverted[] = $word.'-'.$matches[$word]++;
        }
        else
        {
            $wordsConverted[] = $word.'-0'.$matches[$word]++;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        $matches[$word] = 2;
        $wordsConverted[] = $word;
    }
}


foreach($wordsConverted as $convertedWord)
{
    echo $convertedWord."</br>";
}

?>
```

outputs:

```
gold
blue night
silver morning
about earth
sun vs king
blue night-02
```

Comment: and how to update column `title` with the new values?

Comment: With a simple SQL UPDATE statement on the primary key? Dunno, you haven't provided a table structure.